# Disable "Create Audio Playlist" and "Create Video Playlist" in Add Media

Tags: uploads

I would like to disable "Create Audio Playlist" and "Create Video Playlist" as you can see in the screenshot. I've tried to hide the links with css. I've inspected the elements but there're no ID selectors for the links, just a class selector (.media-menu-item). This means it will hide all the links with this class selector. Or is there any option I can do to hide only those two links?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: You will have to look into the plugin or theme that adds this. With no other information it's unlikely anyone can help.

Answer (score 1):

I think u can do that with hooks too: Add this in functions.php in your theme:

```
add_filter( 'media_library_show_audio_playlist', function() { return false; });
add_filter( 'media_library_show_video_playlist', function() { return false; });
```